# Ubuntu: how to check when kernel was last updated?

Tags: kernel

How to check when kernel was last updated? I know I can use uname to check kernel version but I am particularly interested in *when* last update occurred.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

```
    uname -a
    Linux atp-ome32 3.13.0-51-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 15 12:08:34 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Off-topic, try http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thank you Bastien, this is a good method (as I don't have graphical interface to browse updates history).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this question is kind of off-topic so I'd recommend http://askubuntu.com.

Still, on 10.04, you just had to click System -> Administration -> Synaptic Package Manager -> File -> History

Answered here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history